# Spacing problem with \hfill and paired delimiters

Tags: spacing, enumerate, delimiters

Let's say I want to write a list of exercises using `enumerate`.
For each item of the list, the correct answer is given at the end of the line, and it is written between square brackets. This is how I would write it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $2a=4$ \hfill $\left[a=2\right]$
    \item $2a=1$ \hfill $\left[a=\frac{1}{2}\right]$
    \item $3a=6$ \hfill $\left[a=2\right]$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However, the square brackets at the end of the lines are not correctly aligned to each other:

[image: Bigger brackets get an unwanted space]

I can't figure out the reason of this behaviour: adding `\mathclose{}` after `\right` does not help. It is not an `enumerate` issue, since the problem still appears if I remove the `enumerate` setting and go to a new line manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that because you're using `\left` and `\right`, you're getting a slightly larger (and different) closing square bracket on the line with the fraction. Each slightly larger bracket, by the way, adds a little bit more space around it. Because this is actually built into the character design, eliminating it would be challenging at best. A lot depends on what your solutions on the right look like. You can get away without `\left...\right` on your brackets if you aren't having especially tall answers (e.g., simple fractions should be fine, but `\frac{a^2}{b}` might look weird). Perhaps using color instead of brackets to mark your answers would be better? Or alternatively putting them in boxes instead of brackets. In any event, you would want to wrap everything up in a macro definition, e.g.,

```
\newcommand*[1]\answer{\hfill\fbox{#1}
...
\item $2a=4$ \answer{$a=2$}
```

This has the advantage that you could use the same source for the solution-free question list by defining

```
\newcommand*[1]\answer{}
```

Comment: Thank you very much: I'm trying with boxes and it seems quite a nice solution. Yes, the purpose was to define a new macro, but I was trying to be as clean as I could here (and still, I received a comment saying the question was not understandable).

Comment: @MattiaVedovato I saw that comment. I didn't understand it. ‍♂️